# Node JS Loop Through Array Before Creating Property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have a JSON input which contains data linking it to a secondary model (Users). I need to loop through listingData.Agents to get the index ID and then look up this index id to get the user. I push this to the user id to an array but due to the async the array is blank when the create property function is run. How you manipulate and get data from the array and then run the create once all your data is in place.

Thanks.

```
exports.createProperty = function(req,res,next) {
var listingData = req.body;

listingData.User = [];

_.forEach( listingData.Agents , function(n, key) {
    User.findOne({ agentId : n.AgentId},function(err,user) {
        listingData.User.push(user._id);
    });
});

Property.create(listingData, function(err,property) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(400);
        return res.send({reason:err.toString()});
    }
    res.send(req.property);
})}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind introducing new library into your code, [node-async](https://github.com/caolan/async) could solve your problem.

Using node-async, you code would be:

```
var async = require('node-async')
exports.createProperty = function(req,res,next) {
var listingData = req.body;

listingData.User = [];

async.each(listingData.User,
           function(n, key) {
               User.findOne({ agentId : n.AgentId},function(err,user) {
                   listingData.User.push(user._id);
               });
           },
           function (asyncErr){
               //handle asyncErr first
               Property.create(listingData, function(err,property) {
                   if (err) {
                       res.status(400);
                       return res.send({reason:err.toString()});
                   }
                   res.send(req.property);
               });
           });
```